# SSIS: DtsContainer Name property, what is the max length?

Tags: ssis, containers

Does anyone know what is the max length of an SSIS package **container** name?

Thanks

Comment: It might be up to 4000 chars (what nvarchar could handle), don't see any restriction in the .Net api so that could give you 1 billion characters. Not verified.

Answer (score 1):

You can go over 4k characters.

I repeated the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123` a few times. 4k wasn't an issue but 56544 was. VS allowed me to assign the name to a sequence container but BIDS (2008 R2) became very unhappy shortly afterwards.

Interestingly/amusingly enough, I repeated the same test with the SSIS designer for the upcoming 2012 release and RC0 had no problem with the 50k name. I got as far as 10M characters with RC0 before Notepad++ went haywire and stopped responding (I had just built out 100M string).

Both packages (2008R2 and 2012 RC0) were able to execute just fine from the command line with super-long names.

There are practical limitations to be mindful of, however. If you use SQL Server logging for your packages, the dbo.sysssislog table has defined the length of `source` to be `nvarchar(1024)` so I would expect the package to fail validation.